# Clicking on images to change the position of a background in a DIV using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've tried to build this myself and just simply cannot get it to work.

What I would like to achieve is a row of images, if clicked they simply move the background position of a div.

I'm not sure why I can't get something this simple working. Here's the HTML

```
<div class="target"></div>
<a href="#"><img src="01_thumb.jpg" class="thumb"></a><a href="#"><img src="02_thumb.jpg" class="thumb"></a><a href="#"><img src="03_thumb.jpg" class="thumb"></a>
```

And the CSS:

```
#content .item .target {width:240px; height:385px; margin: 0 0 8px; background-image:url(targetimage.jpg);} #content .item .thumb {width:64px; height: 64px; margin: 0 8px; background-color: #FF609C;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) if the clicked anchor (adjust if they're not the only elements in their parent)and multiply that value to change `.target`'s `background-position`, like this:

```
$("a:has(img.thumb)").click(function(e) {
  $(".target").css("background-position", -$(this).index()*240 + "px 0px");
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent navigating to the # href
});
```

[Here's an example you can check out](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZAY3Q/), if there are many `.item` elements, use `$(this).closest(".item").find(".target")` instead of `$(".target")`.

Comment: Hi Nick, not really what I'm after but thanks. I simply need to move the background position of a div when a link is clicked on. The link is not inside the div, or related to it.

Comment: @rage - Where *are* the links? If there's just one `<div class="target">` you'd just replace `$(this).closest("a").prevAll(".taget:first")` with `$(".taget")`, the above would still apply.  Also, you mention position, but there's nothing dealing with it in the question, is `background-position` actually affected? And if so, what should each link do?

Comment: Hi Nick, each link just shifts the background-position x of .target by 240 pixels

Comment: so link 1 is 0, then 240, then 480

Comment: @rage - answer's updated, see if that's what you're after., you can change `.css()` for `.animate()` to get a transition as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help but can't really get that to do anything. The value should be negative, sorry. I changed that over. Even with this stripped back to a basic header, jquery include, and the script, css, html, nothing seems to work. I'm using Safari 5.0.3

Comment: @rage - you're not providing much information at all, do you have an example page? Here's an example of it working: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZAY3Q/

Comment: @rage - welcome, did that show you the issue, or still having problems?

Comment: Nick thanks for all the help, just out of interest; how would you go about changing this to .animate() ?

Comment: @rage - literally just sway `.css` to `.animate`, add an argument if you wanted a duration other than the default 400ms :)